# intento Crear un código para determinar la frecuencia de un elemento específico

Tags: python

> tengo una lista y necesito utilizar el input del usuario para sacarlo de la lista y imprimirlo solo. mas las veces que aparece. ejemplo (onions: 4)

```
def user_item(self):
    item = input('Item: ')
    file = open('InputFile.txt', 'r')
    d = dict()
    for line in file:
        line = line.strip()
        line = line.lower()
        words = line.split(" ")
        for word in words:
            if word in d:
                d[word] = d[word] + 1
            else:
                d[word] = 1
    for key in list(d.keys()):
        print(key, ":", d[key])
```

Comment: Pero si ya lo tienes hecho. Solo cambia el bucle final que te muestra todas las claves por una línea que muestre la clave que el usuario ingrese. Por ejemplo `key=input("Palabra? "); print(key, ":", d[key])`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Por suerte Python tiene métodos que te facilitan ese trabajo. Solo tienes que leer el archivo de texto y convertir su contenido en una Lista y con el método count() puedes contar las veces que aparece un elemento especificado dentro de una Lista. Podrías hacer algo como esto:

```py
item = input('Item: ').lower()
file = open('InputFile.txt', 'r')
lines = file.read().lower().splitlines()
file.close()

print(item, ":", lines.count(item))
```

la línea 3 hace tres cosas:

1. read() Lee el contenido del archivo y devuelve un string.
2. lower() Convierte el string en minúscula en caso que haya alguna
   mayúscula.
3. splitlines() divide el string en los saltos de línea y devuelve una
   lista.

Comment: Podrías aplicar la misma solución dentro de un ciclo que procesa el archivo línea a línea, evitando leerlo entero a memoria.